# How to install oculus sdk in android virtual device?

Tags: android, testing, emulation, oculus

I have been trying to figure out if it is possible to install the Oculus SDK inside an Android Virtual Device so I can test an android app that is having issues with a specific handset.

On my physical handset, all of the Oculus related files were installed when I put my handset in my Gear VR Headset for the first time.  Given that there is no actual hardware with an emulator I am not sure how to do this?  Has anyone tried to do this yet?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need a GearVR to run a Gear app. You need a phone with the Oculus software installed. You'll need to turn on developer mode on the phone, get the device ID, generate an OSIG file, and build that into the APK.  In the manifest file change

`android:value="vr_only"`

to "vr_dual" and the APK will run outside of the GearVR.

I do **NOT** know if this will work in an emulator, I'd be interested in finding out.

Comment: I am able to run the app in developer mode without using the android:value="vr_dual".  Adding that option, didn't make a difference as far as I can tell.  I was curious to know if it is possible to run an app without using Developer mode and without having the Gear VR Hardware connected.  When I looked at the teardown of the device, the Gear VR provides lenses for extending the bridge of your nose, light sensors for knowing when the headset is mounted, button control for touchpad and back button, as well as some gyros.  So I was trying to understand if I can test without the headset.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to connect a real Gear VR to an emulated Android running virtualbox - if you somehow will be able to get and run an Samsung S6 (or similar) image. Still need the real device, though.

Comment: That's not what I was looking for but thanks anyways.  I am looking for ways to automate testing without the Oculus Hardware.

Comment: @JosephIshak have you been able to find a suitable solution for this issue?

Comment: No, I was never able to figure this out so I abandoned trying to.